# Controlling the environ passed to child process by bash

Tags: linux, bash, environment, child-process

I am using x86_64 GNU/Linux with `bash`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    system("set > setc");                           // A subset of `$ set`

    return 0;
}
```

I can see the file setc contains a subset of `$ set`.
I am feeling curious as to know how the shell (parent process) decides what to supply to child process and what not to?
What if I want to supply more environ variables to child process? How one can control that?

Comment: Also on Superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/879999/ and on UNIX and Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185740/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shell variable can be either exported or not exported. The shell will only pass exported variables to child processes. In bash, you can export a variable(for example, $var) by executing `export var`.